# The ultimate HTTP_REFERER solution for PHP back button?

Tags: php, javascript, back-button, http-referer, strpos

Yes I know, another HTTP_REFERER effort. I cringe when I see it. But it has been handed to me as a solution to a 'go back' problem and it actually works, so...

...the problem is, I don't understand it enough to feel comfortable deploying it live.

I've gone through many many messages here about the perils of HTTP_REFERER, however I am told this code addresses them for this particular task... but I'm not convinced.

So, my Questions are at the bottom of the code below - but FIRST, here is the basis behind it:

This code goes into a shopping cart.  It provides the action of the 'Continue Shopping' button after a user clicks 'view cart'.  Its goal is to provide the most suitable (or, expected) redirection back to where the user came from.

By default, without this code added, the 'Continue Shopping' button of this particular 'view cart' page simply takes the user to the home page of the cart - which sort of blows if the user has navigated a few pages deep to find a set of products or a specific category, or was looking at a product, etc.  So we want to improve on that.  Also, the cart requires javascript to complete a purchase, which the user is warned of if they visit with JS off, so JS on is expected of the user during this operation.  Finally, we wanted to keep the solution to a single block of code, so it can be applied easily and transported to updated versions of the cart with little issue.

The methodology as it was described to me:

1. If a referer is set AND it is not empty AND yes it DOES contain this cart's domain then

   1a. If the referer is the cart page itself, apply a javascript (-1) effect otherwise we'll be stuck in one place

   1b. ELSE go ahead and apply the Referer - Done.
2. ELSE if a refer is set AND it is not empty BUT no it does NOT contain this cart's domain then

   2a. Something is amiss, send them to the home page. (?? why ??)

   2b. ELSE let's apply the javascript (-1) effect. - Done.

The code:

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], HTTP_SERVER) === 0))) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?r=cart') {
        $this->data['continue'] = 'javascript:history.go(-1)';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['continue'] = html_entity_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
else {
    if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], HTTP_SERVER) !== 0))) {
        $this->data['continue'] = 'index.php?r=home';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['continue'] = 'javascript:history.go(-1)';
    }
}
```

My Questions:

1. Ok, so we've combined two suspect methods, and collectively it seems to work.  But what can go wrong with this (Security / Function)?  Is there a showstopper here that I'm missing?
2. What is the second part (2. and 2a.) going to accomplish?  It is explained to me to be an effort to determine if someone is purposely trying to feed a false referer - but it doesn't make sense to me - why do we care to route that person to the home page vs. using the javascript (-1) method?
3. ANY thoughts on improvement?  Those always come in handly ;-)

Thank you for your time in helping with this...

Comment: referer is supplied by the client and is not reliable. you would probably have better luck storing the last page viewed in a session variable.

Comment: Hello, thanks... that's a key point of this post... that issue is *supposedly* addressed in the code, by checking if the referer (1) exists, (2) is not empty, and (3) contains the cart's domain, and then defaulting to the javascript method... it also meets our requirement of being self contained.  I do know there are better solutions involving session variables, etc. but in this case I'm trying to focus specifically on this http_referer version, to see if it is viable in this application or not...

Comment: Never rely on JavaScript as a fallback!

Comment: @Nev - Thanks for the reply... is that due to the prospect of it not being available?  Or are there other reasons?  I originally considered adding a noscript tag to the 'view cart' template that displays a link to take the user to the homepage when no JS (which was the default action of that link anyway) - but as the cart requires javascript for most of its key features, those with JS off are already seeing a message with a link to visit our static catalog, so it's unlikely they would be trying to navigate the online cart in that condition.

Comment: Yes, those without JS are small in number but those who have gone to the trouble of turning it off (or installing NoScript) generally get more annoyed!

Comment: Agreed.... and those are probably the same people who are blocking their referers!! ;-) I've read about various ways to check if JS is on via php and page source - but in our case, we actually handle non-js users in a nice way which makes this less of an issue, and an extra noscript link would remove the reliance.  Nonetheless, an important point to consider, appreciate the feedback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referer is simply just the last page the user visited before going to the cart.

1. Javascript:history.go() contains an array of visited pages similar to referer, so it can send the user back a page in history. I don't know of what risk that is unless the cart has no timeout. But I'm not much a security person, so better to let someone with more knowledge explain the risks there.
2. if a user jumped from some other website directly into a cart there, then there really should be something amiss and rather than leaving them there, send them to the home page. In this case, java is a client side software, so it wouldn't have a history of browsing your site to use to send the user to your homepage.
3. If you really don't like referer, breadcrumbs are always another option, or $_SESSION['previousPage'] = ....

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply... Hahaha "if you really don't like referer" ... Hey I want to like it though!! ;-) ... It's mainly that I don't trust it from a security perspective, and that's my biggest concern.  Great point on the homepage question... I suppose if it can detect that the user came from an outside site, directly to the 'cart view', then sending them to the home page would at least keep them in the store, and not send them back to the originating site.  Of course, if no referer, then the javascript default would send them back... but seems like an unlikely visit though...? tx

Comment: Unlikely, but not impossible. Especially when you have someone trying to hack your cart ;)